# Automatically answering incoming phone calls

Tags: ios, windows-mobile

Currently i'm developing a mobile app, the app should work on Android, IOS and Windows Mobile. I would like to implement a feature to automatically accept incoming calls from pre defined numbers. In Android this seems to be doable but i can't find any good information about if it can be done in IOS and Windows Mobile.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

(Ps. Its not possible to jail break or root the phone, its for a client.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Talking about iOS the thing you intend is not possible without jailbreak. Every App is sandboxed and has restricted access to OS functions like the call handling.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, can you provide me with a link to information about this subject?

Comment: You can't do this without jail breaking. Answering call will need user interaction.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000976 might be a good point to start.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so for ios i will have to figure out anonther solution, does someone know about windows mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Simply It is not possible. Apple is more concerned about the security than any other providers. Receiving an incoming call is an OS feature that you can't access. You can only access things that will lies within your app.